# Can't get values from my XML file when transforming it with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have created a little application to convert XML which I get out of our system, to a new XML format needed for customers using XSLT. The problem is, I can't seem to be able to retrieve the values of the XML nodes, they're just all empty.

Here is my XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SourceEndpoint" />
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SourceEndpoint">
    <InvoiceAmount>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </InvoiceAmount>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Original XML does have an node called `SourceEndpoint` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

I also tried: `<xsl:value-of select="Envelope/Header/SourceEndpoint" />` instead of a template but I got the same result

### Edit

Here is a snippet my Original XML:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
  <Header>
    <MessageId>{11EA62F5-543A-4483-B216-91E526AE2319}</MessageId> 
    <SourceEndpoint>Test</SourceEndpoint> 
    <DestinationEndpoint>TestInvoice</DestinationEndpoint> 
  </Header>
</Envelope>
```

`Envelope` is the root of the whole file

In the Transformed XML, test looks like: `<test />`

Comment: Please show us the XML input document. In particular we need to see any namespace declarations and of course the structure of the XML. Is `SourceEndpoint` the root element? Otherwise doing `select="SourceEndpoint"` in the template with `match="/"` does not make sense.

Comment: I updated my answer to show some of the XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The XML file is in a default namespace -- not in the "null" namespace. This makes a huge difference**.

Search for XPath and default namespace and you'll find numerous good answers.

In essence, you must define the same namespace in the XSLT transformation associating a prefix (say "x") to it.

Then in any XPath expression (a match pattern is a kind of XPath expression) use `x:someName` instead of `someName`.

**One additional issue with the provided code** is that it attempts to access the element `SourceEndpoint` as the top element of the document -- and the top element in this case has a different name.

**Correcting these two issues, we get the following transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message"
 exclude-result-prefixes="x">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <test>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/x:SourceEndpoint" />
        </test>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:SourceEndpoint">
        <InvoiceAmount>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </InvoiceAmount>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided  XML document:**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Message">
    <Header>
        <MessageId>{11EA62F5-543A-4483-B216-91E526AE2319}</MessageId>
        <SourceEndpoint>Test</SourceEndpoint>
        <DestinationEndpoint>TestInvoice</DestinationEndpoint>
    </Header>
</Envelope>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
   <InvoiceAmount>Test</InvoiceAmount>
</test>
```

Comment: It's still empty, I already had a prefix `msxsl` so I used that instead of x but `test` was still empty. If I do `<xsl:apply-templates />` then I can see the whole of my xml document

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, You should use the *exact* code of this solution -- it is tested and verified to produce the provided result. Certainly, if you use other code, then you are most likely to get different results. The fact that you are trying to use the msxsl namespace instead of the default namespace of the document shows that you don't understand both the problem and the solution.

Comment: But when I use `x`. It says Prefix 'x' is not defined.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, Just copy and paste the XSLT code from this answer -- you get errors only because you use different code.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice you changed the link too!

Comment: My InvoiceAmount tag looks like: `<InvoiceAmount xmlns="">Test</InvoiceAmount>` tho?

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, Your question is fully answered. Please, ask new, additional questions as separate SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the node use

```
  <xsl:template match="//SourceEndpoint">
    <InvoiceAmount>
      <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
    </InvoiceAmount>
  </xsl:template>
```